# In Pyspark, how to map a column to other values via dictionary (key of dictionary are tuple)

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, mapping

I am trying to convert a column called 'xyz' in a pyspark dataframe into some other values. For example, in xyz col, if cell values are 1 or 3 or 5, map them to 'A' etc. I know you could just write dict as dict = {1: 'A', 3: 'A',5:'A', ...} but i would prefer to make it like dict = {(1,3,5):'A', (2,4,6): 'B', ...} I have write some code and feel i am close but got some errors.

```
from pysapark.sql.functions import col, udf
import pyspark

df = sqlContext.table(table_a).limit(15)

dict_a = {(1,2): 'A', (3,4): 'B', (5,6): 'C'}
dict_b = {(3,6): 'A', (5,1): 'B', (2,4,7): 'C'}

mapping_lookup = {'map_a': dict_a, 'map_b': dict_b}

### udf to do map the column values with given dict name
def translate_(col):
some_dict = mapping_lookup['map_a'] 
dict_len = len(some_dict.keys())
for i in range(0, dict_len):
    if col in some_dict.keys()[i]:
return some_dict.values()[i]

###below works and return 'B' if use map_a
translate_(3)

### below does not work and gave error says "assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"" 
df1 = df.withColumn('new_col', translate_('xyz'))
```

the idea is to map the column values to other values via given dictionaries. so my ultimate goal is to give dict name (map_a or map_b) and a column name to do mapping. see the udf i want to get below:

```
 def translate(dict_name):    
  def translate_(col):
     some_dict = mapping_lookup[dict_name] 
     dict_len = len(some_dict.keys())
     for i in range(0, dict_len):
         if col in some_dict.keys()[i]:
             kkk = some_dict.keys()[i]
     return some_dict.get(kkk)
 return udf(translate_)
```

i have made an udf that works for pyspark if the keys and values of dictionaries are only 1 to 1 map, e.g. 1 to A, 2 to B. but not sure if keys are tuples, how to make it work?

```
### code below works for pyspark dataframe and map the values to deisred

def translate(dict_name):    
  def translate_(col):
    some_dict = mapping_lookup[dict_name] 
    return some_dict.get(col)
return udf(translate_)
```

thank you for your input/help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out as shown below:

```
def a_to_b_map(dict_name):    
 def translate_(col):
     some_dict = mapping_lookup[dict_name] 
     dict_len = len(some_dict.keys())

     temp_key = (9999,)
     for i in range(0, dict_len):
         if col in some_dict.keys()[i]:
            temp_key = some_dict.keys()[i]
             break

     return some_dict.get(temp_key)
 return udf(translate_)
```